# import module from the module db in the query console

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When executing test code from the query console, is there anyway to import XQuery modules that are located in the modules db? I am assuming that the QueryConsole is set to only load modules from the filesystem, which is why I am getting a module not found when I try to load mine.

I am looking for an easy way to test out the XQuery code that I have written, and what I am doing now is to simply paste the whole code with all the functions across multiple modules into the same query tab in order to test.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how they go about testing their xquery modules for MarkLogic?

**Update**

I tried with the suggestion below, specifying the content db instead of the modules db.  But I still have no success.

[image: contents in the modules db]

[image: query console with the content db selected]

And the error I get is:

```
XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /AbbVie/authorization/lib/authorization.xqy not found
```

**Resolved**

When attempting to follow the advice, I loaded the library files into an incorrect path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can import modules with query console. You do this by first changing the content source. This is a drop down on the top left. It shows all the databases. If you have application servers setup it will pair the content database and the modules database that the application servers have. For instance:

```
Documents (Modules: /, server: App-services)
```

The first name shows the content database. In between parenthesis you first get the name of the modules database, followed by the modules root. In case of custom app-servers you can also see the name of the app-server after `server:`

So, for you its probably a matter of picking the correct content source. Once you do that then you just need to `import module` to get the correct module. If its a content and module database pair based on an application server it will take the modules root from the application server configuration into account.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Feel free to nick text from my answer to merge. I'll delete mine..

Comment: Only a few minutes Behind me. Thanks. I like the example you gave and the explanation of whats given in the drop down.

Comment: If your desired combination doesn't show up in the list, create an app-server with the correct combination first. If you don't want to create an app-server for this purpose, you will have to use `xdmp:eval` to set context like modules db and modules root yourself..

Comment: Ok.  Maybe my issue was that I was picking the modules database in the drop down.  I'll try with the content db that is paired with the module db, and give it a try.

Comment: I updated my question with more details.  Selecting the content db/module db pair in the dropdown did not work.

Comment: Never mind.   I had the mlcp update prefix mistyped when I attempted to follow your advice.  This is now resolved. Thanks everyone.